# Pandas Dataframe Apply - lambda function appending to list

Tags: pandas, list, append, pandas-apply

I have a list contained in a column of a pandas dataframe. And I want to append the value in the "price_label" column to the list.

I'm currently using a function i've made to do this, but is it the best way? I feel like I am missing something here?

My method works, but its not pretty. Any suggestions.

List before:

```
+---+--------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+-------+------------------------------+-------------+
|   | prodref      | prodcateg | webproddesc                             | price | categories                   | price_label |
+---+--------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+-------+------------------------------+-------------+
| 0 | 1004 10-14MM | STR4      | Gold Plated Bracelet 1004 - 10-14MM     | 5.98  | [Gold, Plated, Bracelet]     | 1           |
| 1 | 1004 16-22MM | STR4      | Gold Plated Bracelet 1004 - 16-22MM     | 5.98  | [Gold, Plated, Bracelet]     | 1           |
| 2 | 1007 10-14MM | STR4      | Bi-Colour Bracelet 1007 - 10-14MM       | 5.98  | [BiColour, Bracelet]         | 1           |
| 3 | 1007 16-22MM | STR4      | Bi-Colour Bracelet 1007 - 16-22MM       | 5.98  | [BiColour, Bracelet]         | 1           |
| 4 | 1010 10-14MM | STR4      | Stainless Steel Bracelet 1010 - 10-14MM | 5.98  | [Stainless, Steel, Bracelet] | 1           |
| 5 | 1010 16-22MM | STR4      | Stainless Steel Bracelet 1010 - 16-22MM | 5.98  | [Stainless, Steel, Bracelet] | 1           |
| 6 | W108/22      | STR1      | Grey Calf Watch Strap (S) - W108/22     | 4.18  | [Grey, Calf, Watch]          | 1           |
| 7 | W404/14      | STR1      | White Lizard Grain Strap (S) - W404/14  | 5.98  | [White, Lizard, Grain]       | 1           |
| 8 | W404/18      | STR1      | White Lizard Grain Strap (S) - W404/18  | 5.98  | [White, Lizard, Grain]       | 1           |
+---+--------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+-------+------------------------------+-------------+
```

function :

```
def appendPrice(vert):
    cat_list = vert["categories"]
    cat_list.append(vert["price_label"])
    return cat_list

test["categories"] = test.apply(lambda x:appendPrice(x),axis=1)
```

Output

```
+---+--------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+-------------+
|   | prodref      | prodcateg | webproddesc                             | price | categories                      | price_label |
+---+--------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+-------------+
| 0 | 1004 10-14MM | STR4      | Gold Plated Bracelet 1004 - 10-14MM     | 5.98  | [Gold, Plated, Bracelet, 1]     | 1           |
| 1 | 1004 16-22MM | STR4      | Gold Plated Bracelet 1004 - 16-22MM     | 5.98  | [Gold, Plated, Bracelet, 1]     | 1           |
| 2 | 1007 10-14MM | STR4      | Bi-Colour Bracelet 1007 - 10-14MM       | 5.98  | [BiColour, Bracelet, 1]         | 1           |
| 3 | 1007 16-22MM | STR4      | Bi-Colour Bracelet 1007 - 16-22MM       | 5.98  | [BiColour, Bracelet, 1]         | 1           |
| 4 | 1010 10-14MM | STR4      | Stainless Steel Bracelet 1010 - 10-14MM | 5.98  | [Stainless, Steel, Bracelet, 1] | 1           |
| 5 | 1010 16-22MM | STR4      | Stainless Steel Bracelet 1010 - 16-22MM | 5.98  | [Stainless, Steel, Bracelet, 1] | 1           |
| 6 | W108/22      | STR1      | Grey Calf Watch Strap (S) - W108/22     | 4.18  | [Grey, Calf, Watch, 1]          | 1           |
| 7 | W404/14      | STR1      | White Lizard Grain Strap (S) - W404/14  | 5.98  | [White, Lizard, Grain, 1]       | 1           |
| 8 | W404/18      | STR1      | White Lizard Grain Strap (S) - W404/18  | 5.98  | [White, Lizard, Grain, 1]       | 1           |
| 9 | W409/14      | STR1      | Pink Lizard Grain Strap (S) - W409/14   | 5.98  | [Pink, Lizard, Grain, 1]        | 1           |
+---+--------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Just treat each row as a regular list: `test["categories"] += [1]`

Comment: Working with `objects` within a pandas DataFrame is rarely pretty, and it's typically very inefficient. Is there any reason you couldn't instead think of working with dummy columns [Gold, Plated, Bracelet, BiColour, Steel, Stainless, Grey, Calf, Watch, White, ...] Sure it might seem a bit excessive, but I bet it's far easier to figure out how many Gold Bracelets you have with the dummy columns. That and in terms of dummies your price_label column is fine as is.

Comment: Thats what I was planning to do @ALollz but I had them in a list, so was going to split them out from there. Maybe I'm going about it the wrong way.

Comment: @FelipeLanza unfortunatly the price label will not always be 1, I should have shown that in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ALollz pointed out, using a list inside a a Series or DataFrame is rarely the way to go.

That said, if you want to keep your pattern for now you could drop the `appendPrice` altogether:

```
test["categories"] = test.apply(lambda x: x.categories + [x.price_label],axis=1)
```

Otherwise you could share more color on what exactly are you trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: I am looking to end up with the dataframe containing all products as rows and columns for each feature of the product that I have extracted from the description. It would have a binary classification for each (i.e. yes or no). This will be to form a recommender system of some sorts; I’m just experimenting at the moment.

Comment: Perhaps one way to tackle this would be to create some helper/parsing function that takes the "categories" column and breaks it down into multiple columns. And preferably not all of them should be binary (e.g. you might have a "color" column as opposed to having each one as a separate category field).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

```
df["categories"]
0        [Gold, Plated, Bracelet]
1        [Gold, Plated, Bracelet]
2            [BiColour, Bracelet]
3            [BiColour, Bracelet]
4    [Stainless, Steel, Bracelet]
5    [Stainless, Steel, Bracelet]
6             [Grey, Calf, Watch]
7          [White, Lizard, Grain]
8          [White, Lizard, Grain]
Name: categories, dtype: object
```

and `df['price_label']` as `int`, the following will do:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row["categories"] + list(str(row["price_label"])), axis=1)
0        [Gold, Plated, Bracelet, 1]
1        [Gold, Plated, Bracelet, 1]
2            [BiColour, Bracelet, 1]
3            [BiColour, Bracelet, 1]
4    [Stainless, Steel, Bracelet, 1]
5    [Stainless, Steel, Bracelet, 1]
6             [Grey, Calf, Watch, 1]
7          [White, Lizard, Grain, 1]
8          [White, Lizard, Grain, 1]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

This line of code will do what you requested. It will append the value from the price_label column to the end of each categories row. This operation is more efficient than a df.apply(), for larger data.

```
list(map(lambda k: df['categories'][k].append(df['price_label'][k]),df.index))
```